# Allow php tags in htmlpurifier

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

htmlpurifier turns out a simple `<?php` tag into `&lt;?php` 
Is there any way to prevent this? I want to keep the php tags.. Thanks!

Comment: this is not a direct answer, but you may get help from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326121/how-to-allow-code-in-htmlpurifier

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I guess I have to convert them back with preg_replace if no official way is exist. :)

Answer (score -1):

Simple, you need to edit the [whitelist](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/smoketests/printDefinition.php). Follow the instructions to allow anything you like.

Comment: it is a comment as of now. please include a summary or examples for better answer.

Comment: Sorry sir, I do not know what to do with this.. :(