# HTMLPurifier ignore WMD/ WYSIWYG code samples/tags like SO does

Tags: php, wysiwyg, htmlpurifier, wmd

I am testing a WMD editor like the one used here, on SO, to allow markup in user input. I apply [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) on the input and it cleans all the bad tags. However, like SO, I also want to allow code samples
`like this (backticks)`

```
like this (indentation)
```

```
and even like this (with pre and code tags)
```

however if the user puts some nasty code in the sample, for instance:

```
<script>alert("annoy");</script>
```

the HTMLPurifier removes it.
How can I allow any user input for code samples with HTMLPurifier?

---

I saw [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326121/how-to-allow-code-in-htmlpurifier?rq=1) but the answer is just to vage

Comment: Can you tell us what part of the answer of the other question you are struggling with? Do you need help with the regular expression, or with the syntax of `preg_replace_callback()`? Are you unfamiliar with CDATA? Are you unsure _where_ you should be transforming your code blocks to CDATA blocks in your code flow? Also, how does the code that HTML Purifier is destroying look? Since you're working with a WYSIWYG, you may be running into this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34962904/245790

Comment: Thanks for the reply @pinkgothic, thus far i have used `preg_replace_callback` to escape the literals and it works, but it looks like an unsafe way to do this, i wonder if htmlpurifier has any configuration that allows anything (event malicious code) inside the tags (which could also be backticks or just indentation). And yes, I am unfamiliar with CDATA.

Comment: The approach Edward suggested works like this: Immediately before purification, take the HTML that you want to purify, use regular expressions on it to find your `<code>...</code>` blocks, and replace them with `<code><![CDATA[...]]></code>` blocks (the stuff denoted by `...` does not change at all). Then proceed with purification.

Comment: Can you show us the HTML code that is getting mangled, though? Like I said in my first comment, the problem may just be the way you're using your WYSIWYG. The most common error is not using `htmlspecialchars()` on the HTML before putting it into the WYSIWYG's `<textarea>`. If you're not escaping the HTML before putting it into the `<textarea>`, change your code so it *does* escape it. Not only is that necessary, it may fix the issue with the code blocks! See the answer I linked in my first comment for an explanation.

Comment: @pinkgothic Is CDATA default HTMLPurifier behaviour? As for your last comment, I'm already using `htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: CDATA is just a different form of escaping in HTML (and HTML Purifier leaves escaped text in HTML alone, since it's never dangerous). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean

Comment: @pinkgothic i will ajust my code to use CDATA and test it, if you want to formalize yourr comment you can post a question and I'll approve it, cheers